# Evaluate goodness-of-fit of estimation of Pareto-like distribution

Tags: goodness-of-fit, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, cumulative-distribution-function, pareto-distribution

I would like to evaluate the goodness-of-fit of the following (*Pareto*-like) distribution:
$$
f(r) = \sigma \centerdot r^{-\rho}
$$
The function estimates the population of cities given the rank $r$ in a popularity ranking.

I have not estimated the parameters ($\sigma$ and $\rho$) from the sample. However, I am unsure how to apply *Kolmogorov-Smirnov* (or similar tests) because I do not know the *CDF* of $f(r)$.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: This looks like an equation, not as a function. Where is the variable? And what is the domain (i.e. the support) of the variable?

Comment: I have altered the question and, hopefully, clarified your questions.

Comment: If $f(r)$ denotes the population, then this is the _functional_ determination of the random variable "population", as a function of the random variable "ranking", which in turn is a categorical (discrete) variable. So in order to obtain the probability mass function of the random variable "population", one needs to start with the probability mass function of the r.v. "ranking". But it may be the case that $f(r)$ is the postulated probability mass function of the random variable "ranking"... which of the two holds in your case? (obviously, these are two totally different situations).

Comment: I have evaluated the form of the function beforehand, so we can say the form is "correct". In the current step, I would like to evaluate the goodness of one specific way to estimate $\sigma$ and $\rho$ by making use of a sample of real data.